# How to expand/collapse list of information in a webpage using a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to web programming and wants to create a link that will expand and collapse a list of information. I was able to do this using radio buttons as shown in the following example bellow. 
Instead of using a radio button or a regular button, can you please tell me how can I achieve this same feature using a clickable link. Ex: [+ More](http://#)

Please show me with an example if possible.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function OnChangeCheckbox1 (checkbox) {

            if (checkbox.checked) {
                document.getElementById(checkbox.name).style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById(checkbox.id).style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        function OnChangeCheckbox2 (checkbox) {

            if (checkbox.checked) {
                document.getElementById(checkbox.name).style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById(checkbox.value).style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    </script>


* Some Information about X<br>
<label class="radio"><input id="id_clasification2" type="radio" name="moreid1" value="lessid1" onclick="OnChangeCheckbox2 (this)" />+ More</label>
<span style="display:none" id="moreid1" ><label for="id_advisor">First some text<br>First more text</label></span>
<label style="display:none" class="radio" id="lessid1"><input id="lessid1" type="radio" name="moreid1" value="Staff/Faculty" onclick="OnChangeCheckbox1 (this)"/>- Less</label>

<br><br>

* Some Information about Y<br>
<label class="radio"><input id="id_clasification2" type="radio" name="moreid2" value="lessid2" onclick="OnChangeCheckbox2 (this)" > + More</label>
<span style="display:none" id="moreid2" ><label for="id_advisor">Second Some text<br>Second more text</label></span>
<label style="display:none" class="radio" id="lessid2"><input id="lessid2" type="radio" name="moreid2" value="Staff/Faculty" onclick="OnChangeCheckbox1 (this)"/>- Less</label>

<br><br><br>
Aditional Information goes here
```

[image]

Working Code: https://jsfiddle.net/hey4769/owpat8zf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's an idea to use value/name/id attributes, please be aware this does not work for all elements. Also name attribute (at least for some elements) is deprecated in html5.

So I've chosen to use data attributes. And, as I'm spoiled with using jQuery, I decided to test some things in javascript, and included 2 different functions, one using `this` and another passing the event.

For selecting the elements to show/hide I've used `document.querySelector`, which works like a css selector.

I'm also changing the text on the a element after clicking it. Last I've added some console logs. Hope it's useful!

https://jsfiddle.net/hamu21gj/

Comment: Thank you all for the detailed explanation and showing me with an examples. It was very helpful to understand.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, querySelector works only for first matching element (even classes). For multiple elements use querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1):

you can you href to add your javascript like this:

```
href="javascript:MyFunction"
```

I changed your code a little bit just to make an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/owpat8zf/3/